# Disable specific Dropdown Option in Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have a dropdown in my laravel application.

And I have three different user roles as well

```
1/ user
2/ regional admin
3/ super admin
```

Regional admins and Super admins can create new users from the dashboard.

When they are creating a new user, they can assign a user role through the form.

I'm using a dropdown to select the user role.

user roles options are loading from Database.

following is the code for display dropdown on my blade.

```
 {{ Form::select('roles',array_merge(['' => 'Veuillez sélectionner un rôle'],  $roles ), Request::old('Roles'),array('class' => 'form-control txt_txt')) }}
                    {!! $errors->first('roles', '<span class="help-block" role="alert">:message</span>') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('role_id','null', array('class' => 'form-control txt_none')) !!}
```

Now my issue is,

If the logged-in user is a Regional Admin, I want to disable the Admin option from the above dropdown option. Because Regional admins cannot create super admin users.

But the logged-in user is a super admin all the role options are enabled for them...

How can I disable the 'Admin' role option for non-super admin users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than disabling options, why don't you show the only available options for a certain user for their role ids

From your controller first you need to catch the current logged in user's role id

Assuming you are storing user's role id in users table you can simply,

```
$user_roleId = Auth::user()->role_id;
```

Now, as you have the logged in user's role id, you can change the eloquent accordingly using simple if else

```
if($user_roleId=='1'){
//eloquent here
}
else if ($user_roleId=='2'){
//eloquent here
}
```

You have not provided enough details in your question to give the exact eloquent.